# Marketing cloud - Journey Builder - Smart capture entry

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, smart-capture

What is the URL of a Cloud page used as a entry point in a Journey?
Is it the URL i see on top of the cloud page edit page? But there it's not yet connected to the Journey right?

Let me rephrase the question. I used a smart capture form on a cloud page as the entry of a journey build in Journey Builder. I activated the journey. How do i now get on the page?

Regards,
Maxcim

Answer (score 0):

You only have to publish the cloudpage and once you submit the form you will automatically enter into the journey.

The cloudpage can be published in a website as an iframe, as a link in the email...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you’re trying to get to the actual published landing page of the Cloud Page. Yes, it is the URL at the top of the CloudPage edit page. You will need to publish the page in order for the page to be live.

More on CloudPage URLs here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_personalized_urls.htm&type=5